# Pop Up not working when calling from method in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

if (Session["DtaMade1"] != null)
    {
       dtaMade = (string)Session["DtaMade1"];
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "jscript", 
                                                 "alert('" + dtaMade + "');", true);
    }
```

I am using the following code to Open my **Popup**

However it isn't working plus all my controls are inside an Update Panel

Comment: Youe sample missing "open my popup" portion... only `alert`...

Comment: It works fine on other pages

Comment: Please consider re-reading your question to make it more clear. So far you have some piece of code with XSS script injection, than sentence about "following code to Open my Popup" without code that follows, and "isn't working" without any particular details (like error messages from browser's console) - not the most helpful information for someone to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript functions in pageLoad event instead of document.ready or window.onload when you are using Update Panel . Please check the link. http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: Try    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + strScript + "');</script>");

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "runAlert()");


 function pageLoad() { 
function runAlert(){
alert('hi');
}
}   try this

Answer (score 0):

you are just alerting your `dtaMade` object , no function to open a popup is being supplied in the script....

Comment: It opens on its own doesn't need any extra script

Comment: can you throw some light which library help it to open. what are the parameters that are required to open it....... Nothing opens by it own you need to initiate the call some where to open it.....